# Lambda expression in ToDictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

To convert a list to a dictionary, we can do it easily with the follwing:

```
list.ToDictionary(v=> v, v=>true);
```

For the first parameter in `ToDictionary`, I can understand the first parameter is the element of the dictionary. But what is meant by `v=> true`?

The second parameter should be of the type `IEqualityComparer`. What purpose does this serve? How is `v=> true` same as `IEqualityComparer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) is the method is used.

The second parameter (v => true) is the **elementSelector** (*A transform function to produce a result element value from each element*).

A list with the elements `1`, `2` and `3` would result in a dictionary with the following mapping (all values are `true`):

```
1: true
2: true
3: true
```

Comment: Or this method in English ;-) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx

Comment: A Dictionary<TKey,TValue> is as the name suggests a _dictionary_ it is used to look up a value with a key. If you don't have and don't need a value, you're probably much better off using a HashSet<T>

Answer (score 1):

When your list has [1,2,3,4] and you convert it to a dictionary by `list.ToDictionary(v=> v, v=>true);` then your dictionary has this values

```
[1,true]
[2,true]
[3,true]
[4,true].
```

The first value is the key the second is the value

EDIT:

just as @dkson said the second parameter is an **elementSelector**. You can see this in intellisense when you go to the 3rd of 4 entries :)

Comment: Yes, but the Intellisense shows the secodn element in ToDcitionary has to be `IEqualityComparer`

Answer (score 1):

You Take a look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx). This is the overload taking a second `IEqualityComparer` argument:

```
ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, IEqualityComparer<TKey>)
```

However, in your example you are using the overload which takes a `Func<TSource, TElement>` which is responsible for generating the *values* of the dictionary:

```
ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, Func<TSource, TElement>)
```

(In your case, all values are simply `true`)